# Waiting time to charge shared preferences is too long

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a user profile class on my app:

```
class Perfil extends StatefulWidget {
  const Perfil({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PerfilState createState() => _PerfilState();
}

class _PerfilState extends State<Perfil> {
  final _util_preferences = UtilidadPreferences();
  var _estado_autenticacion = false;

  String _id = "";
  String _email = "";
  String _imagen = "";
  String _token_firebase = "";
  String _nombre = "";
  String _apellidos = "";
  bool _verificada = false;
  bool _activa = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getEstadoAutenticacion();
  }

  void getEstadoAutenticacion() {
    var estado =
        _util_preferences.recibirEstadoAutenticacion().then((value) async {
      value == null
          ? _estado_autenticacion = false
          : _estado_autenticacion = value as bool;
      print(
          "valor autenticacion en perfil:" + _estado_autenticacion.toString());

      if (_estado_autenticacion == false) {}

      _estado_autenticacion = _estado_autenticacion;
      _id = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioId();
      _email = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioEmail();
      _nombre = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioNombre();
      _apellidos = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioApellidos();
      _imagen = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioImagen();
      _token_firebase = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioTokenFB();
      _verificada = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioVerificado();
      _activa = await _util_preferences.recibirUsuarioActivo();

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    localizationsDelegates:
    context.localizationDelegates;
    supportedLocales:
    context.supportedLocales;
    locale:
    context.locale;

    var _esp = false;
    var _en = false;
    var _ca = false;

    int count;
    //idioma actual
    var actual = EasyLocalization.of(context)?.locale;
    if (actual?.languageCode == "es") {
      _en = false;
      _esp = true;
      _ca = false;
    }
    if (actual?.languageCode == "en") {
      _en = true;
      _esp = false;
      _ca = false;
    }
    if (actual?.languageCode == "ca") {
      _en = false;
      _esp = false;
      _ca = true;
    }
    ;
    print("Idioma actual bool esp:" + _esp.toString());
    print("Idioma actual bool en:" + _en.toString());

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(

            //perfil si no esta logeado

            child: _estado_autenticacion == false
                ? Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('IniciarSesion'.tr()),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginPage()))
                              .then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              print("estoy de vuelta en perfil");
                              getEstadoAutenticacion();
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            primary: Colors.red,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('CrearCuenta'.tr()),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SignupPage()));
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            primary: Colors.red,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          ChoiceChip(
                            selected: _en,
                            shadowColor: Colors.teal,
                            elevation: 10,
                            pressElevation: 5,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                            selectedColor: Colors.red,
                            label: Text('English',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            onSelected: (bool selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                context.setLocale(Locale('en', 'EN'));
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          ChoiceChip(
                            selected: _esp,
                            shadowColor: Colors.teal,
                            elevation: 10,
                            pressElevation: 5,
                            label: Text('Español',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                            selectedColor: Colors.red,
                            onSelected: (bool selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                context.setLocale(Locale('es', 'ES'));
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          ChoiceChip(
                            selected: _ca,
                            shadowColor: Colors.teal,
                            elevation: 10,
                            pressElevation: 5,
                            label: Text('Català',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                            selectedColor: Colors.red,
                            onSelected: (bool selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                context.setLocale(Locale('ca', 'CA'));
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                :

                //  perfil si esta logeado,
                Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(_id),
                      Text(_imagen),
                      Text(_nombre),
                      Text(_apellidos),
                      Text(_token_firebase),
                      Text(_verificada.toString()),
                      Text(_activa.toString()),
                    ],
                  )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At this moment it is working fine, but I am experiencing a small issue.

When the class is shown, it should detect if the user is logged in or not.

Depending on this state, the class should show a column or another.

The small issue I am talking about is that during the time that all shared preferences values are been received, the class is showing the first column, it takes only a fraction of a second, but it is not very nice to see.

What should I do to avoid showing the first column while shared preferences are loading?

Comment: You can use FutureBuilder. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך, where exactly?

Comment: You can see from the sample in the link. You need to handle `snapshot.hasData` when the SharedPreferences finish getting the data, `snapshot.hasError` if failed, and handle if not both i.e still progressing.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך, done, it works, thank you